# Ajax Form submit

Tags: ajax, cakephp, jquery, cakephp-1.3

I am new to Ajax. i wanna submit a form through Ajax and save the data sent to the database.

Something like the Facebook Status update - where text area is disabled and then submited. once its saved in the database it comes back and updates the status message on the top. and again the text area is enabled.

this is my form

```
  <?php echo $form->create('StatusMessage', array('type' => 'post', 'url' => '/account/updateStatus', 'id' => 'updateStatus')); ?> 
  <?php echo $this->Form->input('id', array('value' => $user['User']['id'],'type' => 'hidden')); ?> 
  <?php echo $this->Form->textarea('message', array('value' => 'What have you been eating ?')); ?>
```

**Edited: Modified as suggested by 0 RioTera**

Cakephp Action

```
function updateStatus() {

    $this->autoRender = false;
    if($this->RequestHandler->isAjax()) {
        $this->layout = 'ajax'; //THIS LINE NEWLY ADDED

        $this->data['StatusMessage']['pid'] = 0;
        $this->data['StatusMessage']['commenters_item_id'] = $this->data['StatusMessage']['item_id'] = $this->User->Item->itemId('1', $this->data['StatusMessage']['id']);
        unset($this->data['StatusMessage']['id']);
        //debug($this->data);

        if($this->User->Item->StatusMessage->save($this->data)) {
        return true;
        } else {
            echo 'not saved';
        }
    } else {
        echo 'no';
    }

}
```

Javascript code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var options = {
        target: '#output2',
        // target element(s) to be updated with server response 
        beforeSubmit: showRequest,
        // pre-submit callback 
        success: showResponse, // post-submit callback 
        // other available options: 
        //url:       url         // override for form's 'action' attribute 
        //type:      type        // 'get' or 'post', override for form's 'method' attribute 
        //dataType:  null        // 'xml', 'script', or 'json' (expected server response type) 
        clearForm: true        // clear all form fields after successful submit 
        //resetForm: true        // reset the form after successful submit 
        // $.ajax options can be used here too, for example: 
        //timeout:   3000 
    };

    $('#updateStatus').submit(function () {
        // make your ajax call
        $(this).ajaxSubmit(options);
        return false; // prevent a new request
    });

    function showRequest(formData, jqForm, options) {
        $('#StatusMessageMessage').attr('disabled', true);
    }

    function showResponse(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form) {
        $('#StatusMessageMessage').attr('disabled', false);
        alert('shdsd');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using jquery and http://jquery.malsup.com/form/ plugin:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    var options = { 
        target:        '#message',   // target element(s) to be updated with server response 
        beforeSubmit:  showRequest,  // pre-submit callback 
        success:       showResponse  // post-submit callback 
    };
    $('#updateStatus').ajaxForm(options); 
});

function showRequest(formData, jqForm, options) {
    $('#StatusMessageMessage').attr('disabled', true);
}

function showResponse(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form)  { 
    $('#StatusMessageMessage').attr('disabled', false);
}
```

I didn't try it but I hope it helps you

Comment: i have similar code. but showRequest is not taking any thing. why do we need showRequest(formData, jqForm, options) ?

Comment: and the disabling works. but enabling doesnt after submission. how to get back some data from the action i submit to. like since i wanna display the users name and photo and the message and the time. in the wall

Comment: You need the showRequest to disable the textarea when the subimit button is clicked. Now you need to return some data from the action update_status from the controller accounts. The action in this case has not to render the entire page, only data you need (html, json) ($this->autoRender = false). Take some time to explain all the process. You have to read the cakephp manual now.

Comment: Edited the code..i have done that part. are u telling untill some kinda data is not returned back the success call back method wont be called ?

Comment: Yes, the success event is fired only when received a valid response

Comment: i have edited the code. am not sure what you mean by valid code. can you help me out.

Comment: have you checked if you receive a reply from the action with a tool like firebug?

Comment: It should work. You can add Configure::write('debug', 0) after if($this->RequestHandler->isAjax()), in this way avoid to output debug message.

Comment: :( i removed the debugger to test. still same problem. i am not able to trigger the callback. how does it know when its success and when it fails ? do we need to return something specific ?

Comment: check the ajax response with firebug. I don't know why the callback is not triggered.

Comment: Buddy, its my mistake :( the target was pointing to a div which didnt exist :( sorry for the trouble. Thanks a lot.  is there a way to send back some stuff. like i wanna send back the status message and the time.

Comment: what if i want to place those dataat different places ? i mean status message in one div. time in another ?

Comment: I sent you an email. It's better if we continue out of here or we add a lot of comments

Answer (score 2):

i hope that this tutorial will help

http://mohammed-magdy.blogspot.com/2010/10/ajaxformsubmitter.html

Answer (score 0):

This is a function I use to submit forms in cakephp 3.x it uses sweet alerts but that can be changed to a normal alert. It's very variable simply put an action in your controller to catch the form submission. Also the location reload will reload the data to give the user immediate feedback. That can be taken out.

```
$('#myForm').submit(function(e) {
    // Catch form submit
    e.preventDefault();

    $form = $(this);
    // console.log($form);
    // Get form data
    $form_data = $form.serialize();
    $form_action = $form.attr('action') + '.json';
    // Do ajax post to cake add function instead
    $.ajax({
        type   : "PUT",
        url    : $form_action,
        data   : $form_data,
        success: function(data) {
            swal({
                title: "Updated!", 
                text: "Your entity was updated successfully", 
                type: "success"
            },
            function(){
                    location.reload(true);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

This is what a simple action would look like in the controller;

```
public function updateEntity($id = null){
    $entity = $this->EntityName->get($id);
    $entity = json_encode($this->request->data);
    $this->EntityName->save($entity);
}
```